# Can you replace characters in a textbox as you type?

Tags: wpf, input, textbox

We are looking for a way to make a textbox replace certain characters as a person types in it.  Note, we are focusing on the control itself, not bindings, viewmodels, etc.  For the sake of this question, assume there is a window with a textbox sitting in the middle of it and nothing else.  No data, no viewmodel, no bindings, etc.

I've updated the question because it seems all the answers below keep focusing on bindings, dependency properties, coersion, etc.  While I appreciate the suggestions, as I stated above, our control is not a bound control so they aren't applicable.

Now while I could explain the reasons for that, that would make this post about five times longer as it's actually a complex and advanced use-case, but that has nothing to do with the question itself, which is why I've simplified our scenario down to focus on the specific question we're trying to resolve, which is about a textbox control, or possibly a subclass of one replacing characters as you type.

Hope that makes more sense now.

Comment: Do you have a custom TextBox or do you want to appy this behaviour to normal TextBoxes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is using the `TextChanged` event:

```
    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = (TextBox)sender;
        using (tb.DeclareChangeBlock())
        {
            foreach (var c in e.Changes)
            {
                if (c.AddedLength == 0) continue;
                tb.Select(c.Offset, c.AddedLength);
                if (tb.SelectedText.Contains(' '))
                {
                    tb.SelectedText = tb.SelectedText.Replace(' ', '_');
                }
                tb.Select(c.Offset + c.AddedLength, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

This has several advantages:

- You don't go through the entire string every time, just the replaced part
- It behaves well with the undo manager and with pasting text
- You can easily encapsulate it into an attached property which can be applied to any text box

Comment: Bingo! Works like a champ! Also, +1 because I wasn't aware of the e.Changes property.  Few qs though. Are you sure the DeclareChangeBlock is needed? I believe you're already in one during that event.  I tested it by commenting it out and it still seemed to respect undo properly.  Can you give me a case where it doesn't?  And two, wouldn't it make sense to only run the body of the loop if c.AddedLength was positive? It seems to run unnecessarily when deleting as nothing would be added to check. (BTW, I was impressed this even worked when bound to another TextBox, as well as with pasting.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use an IValueConverter. It involves quite a bit of code, but it's the preferred way if you ever want to go the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) path, or just do things the WPF way.

First, create a class that implements IValueConverter

```
public class IllegalCharactersToUnderscoreConverter
    : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var stringValue = value as String;
        if(stringValue == null)
            return value;

        return RemoveIllegalCharacters(stringValue);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Import the namespace containing your ValueConverter

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
```

Create an instance of your converter in Window.Resources

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IllegalCharactersToUnderscoreConverter x:Key="IllegalCharactersToUnderscore" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Use the converter in your binding expression.  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged is required for the text to be converted as you type.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText, 
                Converter={StaticResource IllegalCharactersToUnderscore}, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Again, we're not talking about bindings. We're specifically asking about replacing text in the textbox itself as a user types. In other words, they type a space, but we insert an underscore. It has to handle pasting, etc. and again, has nothing to do with binding as this isn't a bound control.

Comment: First, it was not clearly stated in your question.  Maybe you should edit it.  Not everyone wants to read every comment of every other answer.  Also, explaining a little bit why you can't use binding would be useful and would help people choose the best answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass TextBox you can just override the Metadata of the TextBox Text property

```
public class FilteredTextBox : TextBox
{
    public FilteredTextBox()
    {
        TextBox.TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FilteredTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, null, CoerceMyTextValue, true, UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged));
    }

    private static object CoerceMyTextValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        if (baseValue != null)
        {
            var userEnteredString = baseValue.ToString();
            return userEnteredString.Replace(' ', '_');
        }
        return baseValue;
    }
}
```

And you dont need to use bindings at all, this will just update the internal TextBox TextProperty **as you type**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="428" Width="738" Name="UI" 
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication13" >
    <StackPanel>
        <my:FilteredTextBox />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Comment: I'm familiar with the coerce functionality, but you've applied this to a DP that you've created.  I want to do this with a textbox.  Also, this has nothing to do with binding.  We want this on the control itself.  Not sure this code will work in that scenario.  If I'm wrong, can you update your answer to show it and I'll mark this as the accepted one?

Comment: You can create a custom textbox and handle the KeyDown/KeyUp events and try find the char entered using the `Key` arg and update the string and set the Textbox value to the new value again. , but that would be a lot of work and you are going to run into issues with breaking Text bindings when you re-apply the new value and causing multiple PropertyChanged events

Comment: So the textboxes you are using are not databound to anything?, are you just using `textbox1.Text` to get the value? because you say this has nothing to do with Binding but all WPF value controls are about binding. If you edit the value inside the Textbox how is your bound property going to know its changed? The only other solution would be an `IValueConverter`

Comment: "all WPF value controls are about binding" is a false statement.  In this case, this control is part of a composite control which our viewmodel binds to.  However, inside this control we're doing special handling in its code-behind.  Sorry if I seem snippy, but it's really frustrating to ask a specific question, then get so many answers trying to solve a problem I didn't ask, without understanding what we're trying to do.  We're not looking for advice on how to set up our control.  We are specifically looking for how to replace text as you type in a textbox, either directly or via a subclass.

Comment: Then I dont understand the problem, just update the string in the TextChanged event or KeyUp/KeyDown events, Like in winforms

Comment: I have updated my second suggestion as it may work in your case, I know it still uses coercsion but you dont have to bind anything to it, it will just update the TextBox text as you type, or you can use OnTextChange like the othet answer suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to achieve this thing by handling this in my `ViewModel` property that is bind to `TextBox` itself like below and it works. In this example I replace '!' with underscore. Here i just put the replacement logic in property setter and if there is a change I replaced the text and Raised the propertychange async.

```
        private string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set
            {

                text = value;
                if (text.Contains("!"))
                {
                    text = text.Replace('!', '_');
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => RaisePropertyChange("Text")));

                }
                RaisePropertyChange("Text");
            }
        }
```

and the textbox binding is

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: We're not talking about bindings.  We're specifically asking about replacing text in the textbox itself as a user types.  In other words, they type a space, but we insert an underscore.  It has to handle pasting, etc. and again, has nothing to do with binding as this isn't a bound control.