# Display whitespace in a textbox as a different character

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, formatting, whitespace

How can I display all space characters entered in a `System.Windows.Control.TextBox` as some other character, such as a dot?   ·  ·   ·   ·

e.g.:

> Enter your text: [abc······def]

Ideally I would also want to display the dot in a lighter color than the rest of the text

When the user enters whitespace, the textbox should only *display* something else. Ideally I do not want to modify the actual string. So the internal value of `TextBox.Text` should remain unchanged, and when the user copies the content to the clipboard, or interacts in a similar way with the textbox, they should get spaces and not dots.

The solutions I found in a related [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971198/can-you-replace-characters-in-a-textbox-as-you-type), overriding the OnTextChangedEvent or using an IValueConverter, can replace the the spaces as they are entered, but this will of course also modify the backing string and I would prefer this to be totally transparent to the application and the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a value converter - something like this worked for me:

```
public sealed class WhiteSpaceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = (string)value;
        if (str == null) return value;
        return str.Replace(" ", "·");

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = (string)value;
        if (str == null) return value;
        return str.Replace("·", " ");
    }
}
```

I also added the following to the text box's command binding for `ApplicationCommands.Copy` (so if the user selects and copies the whitespace, they get the acutal space instead of the dot character replacing it):

```
static Converters.WhiteSpaceConverter conv = new Converters.WhiteSpaceConverter();

private void TextBox_Copy_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;

    if (tb != null)
        Clipboard.SetText((string)conv.ConvertBack(tb.SelectedText, typeof(TextBox), null, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
}
```

Giving me XAML like this:

```
<cnv:WhiteSpaceConverter x:Key="WhiteSpaceConverter" />

...

<TextBox FontFamily="Consolas" 
            Text="{Binding ViewModelStringProperty, 
                   Mode=TwoWay, 
                   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                   Converter={StaticResource WhiteSpaceConverter}}" 
            >
    <TextBox.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Copy}" Executed="TextBox_Copy_Executed" />
    </TextBox.CommandBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Caveat emptor: this will end up translating the dot character to a space if the user enters one into the textbox, and would also result in losing that character from the backing string if the converter ran.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that would be to manipulate the value using the `String.Replace` method. You could do this in a [`TextBox.TextChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) handler:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    // take note of current Caret position within TextBox
    int caretIndex = textBox.CaretIndex;
    textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Replace(" ", "•");
    // reset Caret to original position
    textBox.CaretIndex = caretIndex;
}
```

The trick here is to use a character that the user cannot type: `"•"` (Just copy and paste this character). Using this unavailable character, it will be easy to restore the spaces afterwards:

```
string originalValue = textBox.Text.Replace("•", " ");
```

Unfortunately though, you won't be able to colour this dot a different colour without either using a `RichTextBox`, or putting in a lot of effort.

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid modifying the backing string, since it affects more than the display, such as the value the user gets when copy-pasting, and it requires special treatment in two unrelated code blocks: the TextChanged event and the code that accesses and stores the entered values. But if such a solution that leaves TextBox.Text unchanged is not possible I guess this is the only option.