# Explicitly indicating whitespace in a WPF TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, textbox

I want to have a WPF TextBox that, when you type a space in it, shows that space as a dot or some other character (while still storing the space as its value, obviously).

For example, if I type in `<space><space>abc`, I want the TextBox to show `..abc` but if I get its `.Text`, it should still return `<space><space>abc`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202565/display-whitespace-in-a-textbox-as-a-different-character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this solves your problem.

```
public class NewTextBox : TextBox
{

    static NewTextBox()
    {
        TextBox.TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NewTextBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                "n/a",
                TextBox.TextProperty.DefaultMetadata.PropertyChangedCallback,
                new CoerceValueCallback(textValueCallback)));
    }

    private static object textValueCallback(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        return baseValue.ToString().Replace(' ', '.');
    }

    public new string Text
    {
        get { return base.Text.Replace('.', ' '); }
    }

}
```

Comment: It does indeed, although messing around with `Text` is *not* the right way to go when you're using data binding. Easier to just introduce an additional, uncontaminated property.