# WPF DataGrid using wrong NumberDecimalSeparator

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

currently I am facing the following problem.
In my application (which is a plugin for AutoCAD/BricksCAD), i am using a DataGrid with a custom Column, that ensures the input to be in a float-format.
The code for the column looks something like that:

```
public class DataGridFloatColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        TextBox edit = editingElement as TextBox;
        edit.PreviewTextInput += OnPreviewTextInput;
        return base.PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement, editingEventArgs);
    }

    void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        string txt = ((TextBox)sender).Text + e.Text;
        float _;
        e.Handled = !float.TryParse(txt, out _);
    }
}
```

This part works as expected. I am only allowed to input float numbers, separated by a comma. The problem however is, that the DataGrid expects a dot as decimal separator.
Due to this, initial values are represented with a dot, and If I type something with a comma, it simply gets removed when hitting enter... for example 123,4 --> 1234

What I have already tried:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

But when printing `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`, i am getting a comma...

Any suggestions?
Thank you ind advance!

Comment: Perhaps you can try a decimal converter on the user input like this example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831651/replace-comma-with-dot-while-input-in-wpf-datagrid

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it covers your issue, but if I want culture-specific number/datetime formatting in XAML, I put this "hack" into the constructor of my "App.xaml.cs"

```
public App()
{
    FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(                                                                     
                   typeof(FrameworkElement),
                   new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("de-DE")));
}
```

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = myCulture` somehow does *not* do the trick.

Comment: It also works with 'de-AT' btw ;)